# Can I use .ToString().IsNullOrEmpty() on a StringBuilder object

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder, isnullorempty

```
 /*Class definition*/
public class ConcreteClassModel : BaseModel
{
...
public bool IntersectsWith(ConcreteClassModel ccm)
    {
        ccm.StartDateDT = DateTime.Parse(ccm.StartDate);
        ccm.EndDateDT = DateTime.Parse(ccm.EndDate);
        this.StartDateDT = DateTime.Parse(this.StartDate);
        this.EndDateDT = DateTime.Parse(this.EndDate);

        return !(this.StartDateDT > ccm.EndDateDT || this.EndDateDT < ccm.StartDateDT);
    }
}
/*Inside Controller Method*/
List<ConcreteClassModel> periods = LoadAllByParameters<ConcreteClassModel>(
            ccm.CoverId, x => x.CoverId,
            ccm.SectionId, x => x.SectionId);
var intersectingPeriods =
            periods.Where(x => x.IntersectsWith(ccm));
StringBuilder partReply = intersectingPeriods.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (a, b) => a.Append(b));

********if (!partReply.ToString().IsNullOrEmpty())***************************
        {
            string reply =
                "<div id='duplicateErrorDialog' title='Duplication Error'><span> Duplicate Period(s)</br>" +
                partReply + "</span></ div >";

            return Json(reply, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }    
return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The above seems to work fine and if no duplicate date periods are found the null responce will trigger my javascript to save.  However is it ok to use:
    if (!partReply.ToString().IsNullOrEmpty())
As StringBuilder does not have its own .IsNullOrEmpty() equivalent?
Every comment, question etc that I can find relates to Strings only, and cant see anything on MSDN!

Comment: Would that be more reliable? @DrewKennedy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, `partReply` can never be null or empty, because [`Enumerable.Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548651%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) throws an `InvalidOperationException` when there are no input elements. **Your code is crashing.**

In general cases, you can compare the [`Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property with 0, e.g.:

```
if (partReply.Length > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a quick method to help check if your `StringBuilder` object is null or empty:

```
private bool IsStringBuilderNullOrEmpty(StringBuilder sb) {
    return sb == null || sb.Length == 0);
}

//text examples

StringBuilder test = null;
Console.WriteLine(IsStringBuilderNullOrEmpty(test));//true


StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder();
test.Append("");

Console.WriteLine(IsStringBuilderNullOrEmpty(test));//true

StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder();
test.Append("hello there");

Console.WriteLine(IsStringBuilderNullOrEmpty(test));//false
```

Comment: This implementation of `IsStringBuilderNullOrEmpty` creates a garbage string every time it is called. Instead of converting to `string`, query the `Length` property.

Comment: I initially had that, then made a change in case the StringBuilder was, say, 5 whitespace characters, but I suppose that wasn't a requirement. I'll change it back.